# Select multiple elements

Tags: jquery

So I'm able to get multiple select elements and iterate thru them with the following:

```
$('select[name=sel1], select[name=sel2]').each(function(){
```

Well, I thought I could do something like below but doesn't work:

```
var sel1 = $('select[name=sel1]');
var sel2 = $('select[name=sel2]');
//Doesn't work
$('sel1, sel2').each(function () {
////Doesn't work either
$(sel1, sel2).each(function () {
```

Comment: `$('select[name=sel1], select[name=sel2]'.each` missed a bracket before the .each

Comment: there was already a subject title out there and I saw other people doing this to make it unique. Sorry if terrible practice : (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an option too:

```
$.each([sel1, sel2, sel3, ...], function(key, val){
    /* val.on("event", ...  */
});
```

---

I did an example [here.](http://jsfiddle.net/hg27h7gk/)

You can search more about $.each() and arrays [here](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/iterating/).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `add()` to append jQuery objects together:

```
var $sel1 = $('select[name=sel1]');
var $sel2 = $('select[name=sel2]');

$sel1.add($sel2).each(function () {
    // do something
});
```

Comment: yup sel1 and sel2 are not selectors, they are lists. if you want to do multiple selectors this should do it $('select[name=sel1], select[name=sel2]').each